# How to pass a DOM element to "ng-disabled"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

All,

How can I pass the current DOM element to the Angular directive "ng-disabled"?

I do know that messing w/ the DOM in Angular is bad practice.  But I can't think of another - simple - way to do this.  Here is my problem:

I have a button that updates a scope variable when clicked:

```
<button ng-click="target_model.display_detail=true">click me</button>
```

Elsewhere in my template there is code that watches "target_model.display_detail" - when it is true it displays a modal-dialog which includes an Angular directive which gets some data from the server and populates a form *which includes another button like the one above*.

The data structure that I am working w/ is potentially recursive; there are loads of nested "target_models".  So it is possible for a button in a modal-dialog to point a target_model whose form has already been created.  In that case, I just want to disable the button.  I'd like todo something like:

```
<button ng-disabled="ancestor_model_exists(the_current_element, target_model.some_unique_id)">click me</button>
```

Where "ancestor_model_exists" is a function that would check the DOM to see if there is an ancestor element with a particular id.  But how do I know which element to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching DOM manipulations imperatively - the jQuery way, not declaratively - the Angular way.

DOM manipulation is fine... inside directives.  You don't do it in controllers, where you presumably defined that function.

When you get a chance, try to get away with 0 calls to `$` in a sandbox to force you to learn how to do things the Angular way - not because it's "better" in an absolute way - it's just generally better to first learn the toolkit and recommended approaches before doing it your way, anyway.

This should do what you want, except maybe searching beyond multiple ancestors (but I mention how to do that if you need that):

https://plnkr.co/edit/7O8UDuqsVTlH8r2GoxQu?p=preview

**JS**

```
app.directive('ancestorId', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'AncestorIdController',
    require: ['ancestorId'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
      var ancestorIdController = controllers[0];

      // If you wanted to use an expression instead of an 
      // interpolation you could define an isolate scope on this 
      // directive and $watch it.
      attrs.$observe('ancestorId', function(value) {
        ancestorIdController.setId(value);
      });
    }
  }
});

app.controller('AncestorIdController', function() {
  this.getId = _getId;
  this.setId = _setId;

  var id;

  function _getId() {
    return id;
  }

  function _setId(value) {
    id = value;
  }
});

app.directive('disableForAncestorId', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: ['?^ancestorId'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
      var ancestorIdController = controllers[0];

      // Check to make sure the ancestorId is a parent.
      if (ancestorIdController) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          var watch = {
            target: ancestorIdController.getId(),
            actual: attrs.disableForAncestorId
          };
          return watch;

        }, function(value) {
          if (value.target === value.actual) {
            element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          } else {
            element.removeAttr('disabled');
          }
        }, true /* Deep watch */ );
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- The simple happy path. -->
<div ancestor-id="A">
  <button disable-for-ancestor-id="A">'A' === 'A' ?</button>
</div>

<!-- require will match the 'B' before the 'A' because it's closer.
 if you need to match any parent you could use a third coordinating
 directive. -->
<div ancestor-id="A">
  <div ancestor-id="B">
    <button disable-for-ancestor-id="A">'B' === 'A' ?</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- require lets you freely change the DOM to add extra elements separating
you from what you're looking for.-->
<div ancestor-id="B">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button disable-for-ancestor-id="B">'B' === 'B' ?</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- It doesn't blow up if it doesn't find an ancestorId. -->
<div>
  <button disable-for-ancestor-id="B">'B' === undefined ?</button>
</div>

<br>
Dynamic AncestorId test (it will be disabled if the text fields are equal):
<br>
Target AncestorId <input ng-model="targetAncestorId">
<br>
Actual Ancestor <input ng-model="actualAncestorId">
<!-- It doesn't blow up if it doesn't find an ancestorId. -->
<div ancestor-id="{{ targetAncestorId }}">
  <button disable-for-ancestor-id="{{ actualAncestorId }}">'{{ actualAncestorId }}' === '{{ actualAncestorId }}' ?</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It never fails... posting a question on Stack Overflow always makes me realize the answer just minutes later.

The following code gets me pretty close:

**template.html:**

```
<button ng-click="display_if_ancestor_model_exists($event, target_model)">click me</button>
```

**app.js:**

```
$scope.display_if_ancestor_model_exists = function($event, target_model) {
  var ancestor_form = $($event.target).closest("#" + target_model.some_unique_id);
  if (ancestor_form.length) {
    /* don't show the modal-dialog */
    display_msg("This form already exists!");
  }
  else {
    target_model.display_detail = true;
  }
};
```

Of course, I would rather the button just be disabled but I can live w/ this solution for now.